# Loading list of available fonts using c# in WINRT

Tags: c#, windows-runtime

I want to load the list of available fonts into a combobox of a winrt app using c#. It was simple task in .Net but i couldn't find the corresponding API in winrt. How can i do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use DirectWrite. There is a snippet to do it here:

https://github.com/christophwille/winrt-snippets/tree/master/EnumerateFonts

Copy&Paste:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using SharpDX.DirectWrite;

namespace EnumerateFonts
{
    public class InstalledFont
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }

        // Code taken straight from SharpDX\Samples\DirectWrite\FontEnumeration\Program.cs
        public static List<InstalledFont> GetFonts()
        {
            var fontList = new List<InstalledFont>();

            var factory = new Factory();
            var fontCollection = factory.GetSystemFontCollection(false);
            var familyCount = fontCollection.FontFamilyCount;

            for (int i = 0; i < familyCount; i++)
            {
                var fontFamily = fontCollection.GetFontFamily(i);
                var familyNames = fontFamily.FamilyNames;
                int index;

                if (!familyNames.FindLocaleName(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name, out index))
                    familyNames.FindLocaleName("en-us", out index);

                string name = familyNames.GetString(index);
                fontList.Add(new InstalledFont()
                                 {
                                     Name = name,
                                 });
            }

            return fontList;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou isn't there a native way to do it?

Comment: DirectWrite IS the native way! :) I mean you can skip SharpDX and call it from C++ if you're up for mixing languages, but no, there doesn't seem to be a non-DirectWrite way to do it in WinRT.

Answer (score 0):

There is also a way to enumerate fonts without SharpDX. https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/FontExplorer-lets-you-f01d415e#content